# Python PUT Request - Invalid Syntax

Tags: python, api, python-requests, put

I'm using an API that accepts PUT requests. I'm attempting to add in a new description but whenever I use this in my script it's telling me invalid syntax. Any help in addressing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
    payload = {'description' : '<p>This is just some text...</p>'}
    r = requests.put('REMOVED/{}/REMOVED/{}'.format(course['c_id'], 
    course['a_id']), data = payload, headers = {'Authorization': 'REMOVED')
```

Comment: You are missing a closing curly brace near the end of that line.  If the editor you're using doesn't make this obvious, then *you are using the wrong tool for the job*.

Comment: If you're working with the latest version of requests, then this is the syntax of the put request: http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/_modules/requests/api/#put In addition to the previous comment, I also believe you are missing the target url of your put request.

Answer (score 0):

this is possibly because of missing curly brace

```
(... data = payload, headers = {'Authorization': 'REMOVED'})
                                                         ^^^
```

so, what you should better do is pasing variables instead of objects/logic itself.

```
payload = {'description' : '<p>This is just some text...</p>'}
course_id = course['c_id']
another_id = course['a_id']
url = 'https://yoururl.com/{}/{}'.format(course_id, another_id)
headers = {'Authorization': 'REMOVED'}

r = requests.put(url, data = payload, headers = headers)
```

which will let you easily to inspect error.